# How to create specified dpi graph in sas 9.2/9.3?

Tags: graph, sas

I want to create a graph of a specified dpi. I tried but failed. I am new in this field. 
Some magazines require that a graph should be about 8.3 cm for single column and dpi should be larger that 600. I tried the below in sas 9.3 but not found the tif file, it generated a default png, not tif. And this png is 100 dpi. If I created the graph in graph window and "Export image", it was also 100 dpi. Why not 600 dpi?

```
ods listing style=journal image_dpi=600;
ods graphics on / width=8.3cm outputfmt=tiff imagename='afile';
proc gplot data=presid.pre;
plot allsyll*allyear=group;
run;
```

I used SAS 9.2 and used

```
goptions reset=all device=tiffp xpixels=1000 xmax=1.5in
...
```

This created a tif file and the til dpi is much larger than 100 but I can not decide how to set so that the resulting
graph will be 8.3 cm and 600 dpi.

What I want is the graph is 8.3 cm in width and at least 600 in dpi. In Origin software, it seems easy to just input resulting dpi and resulting size for production of a graph. Can I set these parameters in SAS for controlling the size and dpi in SAS?

Thank you very much in advance. I am testing on SAS 9.2/9.3.

Comment: In the future please reference a dataset in SASHELP so that others can run your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ODS Graphics and SAS/Graph procedures are not related. ODS Graphics relates to the SG procedures, such as SGPLOT and SGRENDER. Use the appropriate proc generates your tiff file. In general, the SAS/Graph procedures are a bit antiquated. Most people use the SG procedures these days.

```
ods listing style=journal image_dpi=600 gpath='C:\temp';
ods graphics on / width=8.3cm outputfmt=tiff imagename='afile';
proc sgplot data=sashelp.class;
scatter x=height y=weight/group=sex;
run;
```

EDIT: This still creates a 100 dpi image...but it's scalable and better quality.  I see options in 9.4 but not sure about 9.3, will look into it a bit more.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Reeza. I tested your code, it prompted "...can not load java virtual machine...". I just searched this problem on google and found that this is another problew that is a bit more complicated to solve. I will start another thread for it. Currently, it seems using gplot, and xpixels, xmax in goption is feasible and I can see the an image that is larger than 300 dpi. But I do not know how to set the hsize,vsize in order to have the resulting image with 8.3cm in width, and over 600 dpi.